# How to redirect form action based on selected option value?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a Search Form that will, based on selected option value, redirect the user after clicking on submit button.
Here is my Form code:

```html
    <form method="get" action="http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search" role="search">
      <select>
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    <option value="10">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Canada</option>
    <option value="4">Singapore</option>
    <option value="5">India</option>
    <option value="6">China</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

For example: If we select USA, cause Value is 10, User web page will be redirected to the following URL:

> http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search/USA/USA/10?

I want to add this specific line after question mark:

**checkin=%F%F&checkout=%F%F&adults=0&child=0**

Something like this:

> http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search/USA/USA/10?checkin=%F%F&checkout=%F%F&adults=0&child=0

How can I add it with JavaScript?

I'm looking for JavaScript to make it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you'll add name attribute `<select name="country">`?

Comment: I can't change anything in form section, that's why I should use only JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i changed your code and made new jquery function which may help you! please go through it!

```
      <form method="get" action="" role="search">
      <select id="country">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    <option value="10">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Canada</option>
    <option value="4">Singapore</option>
    <option value="5">India</option>
    <option value="6">China</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="buttonId">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#buttonId").click(function() {
        var country_value = $('#country').val();
       var country_name = $('#country :selected').text(); 
            window.location = "http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search/"+country_name + "/" +country_name +"/" + country_value +"?checkin=%F%F&checkout=%F%F&adults=0&child=0";

    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You really saved me. Thanks again., your code is auto redirect, how can I change it to click on submit button? Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible . you just need to call jquery function on button click! i have corrected code for you!

Comment: hey, i have updated the code above for you!it will work exactly the way you want!

Comment: Yes It's exactly what I want. Thanks for your update. thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to JavaScript `onchange` method. You can use it using `jQuery` or vanilla js. Using plain js.

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search" role="search">
      <select onchange="window.location.href = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search/USA/USA/' + this.value + '?checkin=%F%F&checkout=%F%F&adults=0&child=0'">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    <option value="10">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Canada</option>
    <option value="4">Singapore</option>
    <option value="5">India</option>
    <option value="6">China</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

> **`The href property sets or returns the entire URL of the current page.`**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on javascript side .

```
<input type="submit" value="Send It!" onClick="return ActionDeterminator();">

function ActionDeterminator() {

 //based on the value selected in option drop down u can modify like below
 form.name.action =// set the modified value also you need to add form name to your form
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select id="country_id">
 <option value="10">USA</option>
</select>

 <script>
 $("country_id").on('change', function(){
   var country_id =  $("country_id").val();
   var country =  this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
    var url      = window.location.href;
    var new_url = url + country + country + country_id ? = "F F"&checkout= "F F" & adults=0 & child=0;
    window.location.href = new_url;
})
 </script>
```